# Как в CSS лучше оформлять цвет, словом (например aliceblue), HEX (например #F0F8FF), RGB (например 240,248,255)?

Tags: css3, html5, веб-дизайн

Как в CSS лучше оформлять цвет, словом (например aliceblue) , HEX (например #F0F8FF) , RGB (например 240,248,255) ? 
каким вы видом оформлением пользуетесь в CSS и почему именно этим видом   ?
также подскажите программку , где будет палитра цветов для выбора , и все 3 расшифровки были по цветам . Вот например осмотрелСolorMania, там нужно из списка выбирать какую кодировку выбрать , а мне нужно чтобы сразу на главной странице программки  все 3 вартианта было и чтобы легко было скопировать и вставить в CSS код .
Может подскажите альтернативную программку , чтобы там была также пипетка , чтобы я из сторонней картинки взял цвет и перенес в CSS, возможно плагин для редактора подскажите . Я пользуюсь больше Brackets, также пользуюсь Sublime text 3 , больше конечно нравиться Brackets. Конечно идеально найти плагин чтобы была палитра , сразу 3 варианта кодировки выбранного цвета , а также чтобы была пипетка , чтобы взять на сторонней картинке экземпляр цвета

Comment: Названия цветов используются только во время дебага (за использование на продакшне можно руки отрывать), для скорости, HEX используется по умолчанию в 99,99% случаев, RGBа используется только если есть прозрачность у фона.

Answer (score 1):

Открываем developer tools в любом интернет-проводнике наводим на абсолютно любую часть в браузере и увидим вот такую штучку(смотреть скрин) после клика в этот квадратик появится палитра(смотреть второй скрин) и так же появится возможность выбрать цвет в **rgb** и  **hex**

но так же есть **Colormania** и дополнения для браузеров **ColorZilla**(смотреть третий скрин)

вообще **developer tools** хватает на все задачи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]